# MobaXTerm alt key in Mongo cmd line

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, mongodb, mobaxterm

I'm using MobaXTerm on Windows 10.

I run Mongo command line to interact with my DB.

But as soon as the Mongo shell starts I can't use the Alt key anymore. It just makes an alert sound. It's quite a problem, especially using Mongo, because curly brackets are all over the place and I can't type them.

I tried this on a MobaXTerm CMD tab as well as in a PowerShell tab, no luck so far.

I works fine on a classic CMD window.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean the Alt key, or the Shift key? I don't quite understand how a non-functioning alt key would stop you typing curly brackets.

Comment: @VinceBowdren it is because I'm french and I have a french keyboard and we need to use alt key to type curly brackets...